# PHPMailer '$mail->From = $_POST['email'] not working

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I have set up a contact form on my website that people can use to email me. The form allows them to leave their email behind so I can get back to them somehow. However for some reason no matter what email is left, the system seems to always think that I am the one who sent the email to my own email address, I am guessing this is due to the $mail->Username line of code being me? Although the from should set this, it seems it won't even if I enter the from address directly into the code.

This is the form I am using on my site to submit the form itself.

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="contact-form.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required="true">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="true">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" required="true">
    <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="7" required="true"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
    <button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

The code for the php to be executed when the form is submitted is this.

```
<?php
require 'assets/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                             // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                                    // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                                      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                             // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk';                      // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                          // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                                  // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->addAddress('myemail@hotmail.co.uk', $_POST['name']);    // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                                 // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body    = $_POST['message'];
$mail->AltBody = $_POST['message'];

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some systems just don't allow you to use a from address that's anything other than your own as an anti-forgery measure - because make no mistake, what you're trying to do is forge their address! It's also likely to run into problems with anyone that uses SPF, so you really should not try to do this.

Gmail will allow you to set specific aliases, or use your own domain.

reply-to is probably the most practical solution to this, or just provide a mailto link in the message body.

Comment: Ah ok, I can understand why they wouldn't want me to do that then. If I wanted I could use someone else email to commit crimes etc. I have included the sender email in the body of the text so I know who to reply to, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to "pretend" `$mail->From = $_POST['email'];` that someone have send you an email because as you can see it wont work. If you are trying to send email from someone to yourself just to have ability to push "reply to" button and write to this person use:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email']);
```

Email will be send from your mailbox to your mailbox but you will respond to email posted by the user.

Comment: I was looking for a way to set the actual sender of the email but this doesn't seem to work, I was doing it as through godaddy email forwarding I have an automated reply message for the sender, however I just get the automated reply all of the time instead of the sender. I think I will have to just append the email to the body so I know who to reply to, remove the automated reply from godaddy and build it into PHP myself.

Comment: You could reply normaly this is the option `AddReplyTo`. If you set this the reply will be sent to this address not to yours.

Comment: I changed the `AddReplyTo` line to `$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);` but it will still send the reply to my own email rather than the value of the post data 'email'.

Comment: And in the header the address is properly set? If it is so the problem is in software used to send automated reply - it should use address from `Reply-To`